# Spark-Solr Connector trying to add already existing field with stored=true

Tags: apache-spark, solr, solrj, lucidworks

I am using Spark-Solr connector 3.4.0 with Solr cloud version 7.6.0 in a Spark 2.2.1 Cluster . We have an existing Solr collection with a predefined schema for it. Most of the fields have the `stored` parameter set to `true`, but there are certain fields where we explicitly set `stored=false`. When we try to push data to Solr using the spark-solr connector, we get the following error-

```
org.apache.solr.api.ApiBag$ExceptionWithErrObject: error processing commands, errors: [{add-field={name=taxonomy, indexed=true, multiValued=true, docValues=true, stored=true, type=string},  errorMessages=[Field 'item_id_channel' already exists.
]}],
   at org.apache.solr.handler.SchemaHandler.handleRequestBody(SchemaHandler.java:92)
   at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:199)
   at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:2541)
   at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.execute(HttpSolrCall.java:709)
   at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.call(HttpSolrCall.java:515)
   at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:377)
   at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:323)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1634)
   at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:533)
```

The error says the `item_id_channel` already exists, but this error is only raised for fields for which we have defined `stored=false` (in the Solr schema). I get that the connector wishes to create the schema again for some reason, but it sets the `stored` parameter to `true` which clashes with the predefined schema definition on Solr for this field.

My question is - Is there a way to tell the connector (probably through some option?) that we want the `stored` to be set to `true` for certain fields? And probably a generic way to define other solr parameters for the fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We found the issue that was causing the error. There was a [bug](https://github.com/lucidworks/spark-solr/issues/224) in older versions of spark-solr connector, because of which the connector was trying to add existing fields to the solr schema in case the value of `stored` was `true`. This was fixed in 3.5.5 [release](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/lucidworks/spark/spark-solr/3.5.5/). Hence, once we upgraded our connector to version 3.5.14, the ingestion stared working without any errors.